# C# MVC pass certain rows to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to mvc and cannot figure out how to pass a single column of data to the view.

I have connected my db with ado.net entity model to models.

Then in my controller I have :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

shdesignEntities2 _db;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        _db = new shdesignEntities2();
        ViewData.Model = _db.tblKategoris.ToList();
        return View();
    }
}
```

In the view :

```
@foreach(var m in ViewData.Model)
    {

    <p>Kategori Ad :</p><p> @m.kategori_ad </p>
    }
```

When I do like this , I pass the whole table data to the view where I only need a single column of information.

How can I  only pass data from  the column kategori_ad ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Select:

```
 ViewData.Model = _db.tblKategoris.Select(x => x.kategori_ad).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to find the object that you want and then pass it to the view, do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    _db = new shdesignEntities2();
    ViewData.Model = _db.tblKategoris.Select(x => x.kategori_ad).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

That way `ViewData.Model` only has the object that matches the linq query.

Here you can find more about Linq to retrieve data from a collection in C#: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0):

In Controller

```
    ViewData["Rows"] = (from c in _db.tblKategoris
                        select c.kategori_ad).ToList();
```

View

```
@foreach(var m in (List<string>)ViewData["Rows"])
{

    <p>Kategori Ad :</p><p> @m </p>
}
```

Comment: ViewData?  I feel that we should be promoting strongly typed views if educating a MVC "newbie" :)

Answer (score 0):

You may look at ViewModels. Also by this way you can use smaller part of data exposed.

For example

```
public class KategoriViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Kategori> Kategoriler { get; set; } 
}
```

Then you should add a controller action like

```
public ActionResult Something()
{
       var model = new KategoriViewModel;
       model.Kategoriler = your query..;
       return View(model);
}
```

In view

```
@model KategoriViewModel
@foreach(var m in ViewData.Model)
    {

    <p>Kategori Ad :</p><p> @m.kategori_ad </p>
    }
```